What does output_gradient do in GradientTape().gradient?
I was wondering what the output_gradients argument does in the gradient function of an GradientTape object in tensorflow. According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient, this variable should contain "a list of gradients, one for each differentiable element of target."
Its default value is None.
It isn't very clear what this does exactly.
When I omit the argument, the function calculates the jacobian with respect to some function, for example z <- f(x) so I get dz/dx. I figured that passing the output_gradients dL/dz (with respect to loss L) would calculate their product based on the chainrule, i.e. dL/dx = dz/dx * dL/dz, but testing this out I get a different result. What is done with the output_gradients?? There is no real info in the documentation on this...
Here's some dummy code (from the gpflow repo):
from typing import Optional
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import gpflow

def natgrad_apply_gradients(
        q_mu_grad: tf.Tensor,
        q_sqrt_grad: tf.Tensor,
        q_mu: gpflow.Parameter,
        q_sqrt: gpflow.Parameter,
        xi_transform: Optional[gpflow.optimizers.natgrad.XiTransform] = None,
    ) -> None:
        gamma = 1
        xi_transform = gpflow.optimizers.natgrad.XiNat()

        dL_dmean = gpflow.base._to_constrained(q_mu_grad, q_mu.transform)
        dL_dvarsqrt = gpflow.base._to_constrained(q_sqrt_grad, q_sqrt.transform)

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True, watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
            tape.watch([q_mu.unconstrained_variable, q_sqrt.unconstrained_variable])
            eta1, eta2 = gpflow.optimizers.natgrad.meanvarsqrt_to_expectation(q_mu, q_sqrt)
            meanvarsqrt = gpflow.optimizers.natgrad.expectation_to_meanvarsqrt(eta1, eta2)

        dL_deta1, dL_deta2 = tape.gradient(
            meanvarsqrt, [eta1, eta2], output_gradients=[dL_dmean, dL_dvarsqrt]
        )

        dtheta_deta1, dtheta_deta2 = tape.gradient(
            meanvarsqrt, [eta1, eta2], output_gradients=None
        )

        return dL_deta1, dL_deta2, dtheta_deta1, dtheta_deta2

X_data = tf.ones(5)
num_latent_gps = 1
static_num_data = X_data.shape[0]
q_sqrt_unconstrained_shape = (num_latent_gps, gpflow.utilities.triangular_size(static_num_data))
num_data = gpflow.Parameter(tf.shape(X_data)[0], shape=[], dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)
dynamic_num_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(num_data)

mu = np.array([[0.93350756], [0.15833747], [0.23830378], [0.28742445], [0.14999759]])
q_mu = gpflow.Parameter(mu, shape=(static_num_data, num_latent_gps))
q_sqrt = tf.eye(dynamic_num_data, batch_shape=[num_latent_gps])
q_sqrt = gpflow.Parameter(
    q_sqrt,
    transform=gpflow.utilities.triangular(),
    unconstrained_shape=q_sqrt_unconstrained_shape,
    constrained_shape=(num_latent_gps, static_num_data, static_num_data),
)

q_mu_grad = q_mu.unconstrained_variable * 0.33
q_sqrt_grad = q_sqrt.unconstrained_variable

dL_deta1, dL_deta2, dtheta_deta1, dtheta_deta2 = natgrad_apply_gradients(q_mu_grad, q_sqrt_grad, q_mu, q_sqrt)

dL_deta1 !== dtheta_deta1 * q_mu_grad

Hope that somebody knows and thanks in advance!
